# Using bc through pipes and fork

Tags: c, pipe, fork, bc

I'm trying to get the answer of a char expression using bc through pipes.
I would like first to write the expression in the pipe1, which the bc will read and write the answer in pipe2. For this I am changing the input and output. This does work if I do not use a char[] and just put the expression in the write :

```
write(pipe1[1], "20*5\n", sizeof("20*5\n")-1) != sizeof("20*5\n")-1)
```

But if I declare a tab, I keep getting the error :

```
(standard_in) 2: illegal character: ^@
```

*Sometimes it is 1 instead of 2*

What I am doing wrong? If someone could explain me, thank you.

Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char resultat[5];
    int pipe1[2];
    int pipe2[2];

    pipe(pipe1);
    pipe(pipe2);

    int resultat_fork = fork();

    if (resultat_fork == -1)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char* expression = "20*5\n";

    if (resultat_fork != 0)
    {
        //printf("I am the parent\n");

        close(pipe1[0]);
        close(pipe2[1]);

        if (write(pipe1[1], expression, sizeof(expression)) != sizeof(expression))
            fprintf(stderr, "write to child failed\n");

        int nbytes = read(pipe2[0], resultat, sizeof(resultat));
        if (nbytes <= 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "read from child failed\n");
        else
            printf("resultat: %.*s\n", nbytes, resultat);

        close(pipe1[1]);
        close(pipe2[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("I am the child\n");

        close(pipe1[1]);
        close(pipe2[0]);
        dup2(pipe1[0], 0);
        dup2(pipe2[1], 1);
        close(pipe1[0]);    /* More closes! */
        close(pipe2[1]);    /* More closes! */

        execlp("bc", "bc", NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute bc\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The variable `expression` is a pointer, not an array.  Use `strlen()` instead of `sizeof`.  (I did mention using `strlen()` in commentary to my previous answer to a previous variant of this question.)

Comment: Alright, please accept my apologise, I didn't really got it on the moment.

Comment: Apology accepted — it can be hard to detect the nuggets of useful information in amongst the detritus of commentary (both within and after an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^@` is the nul character i.e. `'\0'`. This would suggest you are overrunning the end of the string when you write it to `bc`. The problem is here:

```
sizeof(expression)
```

`expression` is not an array, it is a `char` pointer that points to the first character of the string `"20*5\n"` and, if you are on a 64 bit machine, its size is 8. To get the length of the string to send, use `strlen(expression)` instead.

Another thing you need to do, not related to your problem is, in the parent process, after you've read the answer, [wait](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) for the child process to finish. Otherwise, you'll be left with a zombie.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I will try to use wait.

Comment: Note that if the parent exits before the child does, a system process (usually PID 1, `init`) inherits the orphaned child and does not create a zombie.  The only time you get a zombie is if the parent process does not exit until after the child exits, but the parent process does not wait for the child at any stage.  This becomes a problem if the parent creates many zombies; one zombie is seldom a problem, and many processes exit fairly promptly so that the would-be zombies are cleaned up automatically by the system.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
if (write(pipe1[1], expression, sizeof(expression)) != sizeof(expression))
```

You are using `sizeof` operator with `expression` which is a `char*`, if your system is 32-bit, it will result in `4`, which is the size of any pointer variable in your code.

You need to use `strlen(expression)` instead of `sizeof`.

As pointed out in the answer as well, you need to wait for child process to finish its execution and terminate, if the parent process has more than one child processes. Ideally, you should also check the return value of `wait`, which provides you more context on how the child process was terminated.

Comment: Alright I'll try this too, thank you for helping, much usefull.